# how to enable select text in swiper.js

Tags: javascript, slider, swiper.js

I am using this library for swiping, it's working fine as expected but i have this issue of text selection, so how to enable select text in `<div class="swiper-slide>some text </div>`

Comment: can you share the code what you have done ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By default the click event acts as a touch event and the slide follow the mouse movement when you hold it. I have two solutions to select text inside a slide.

**Option 1**

You can wrap your text with a span element with class `swiper-no-swiping` to disable swiping only on the text.

`<div class="swiper-slide"><span class="swiper-no-swiping">some text</span></div>`

**Option 2**

You can use the simulateTouch parameter to disable the click event as touch event in the whole area of the slides.

`new Swiper('.swiper-container', { simulateTouch: false });`